# Nexus can't find artifact that is in Maven Central

Tags: maven, sonarqube, nexus

I have a Nexus server with group-type repository that contains Maven Center. I can see org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1 artifacts (both pom and jar) in Maven Center [[1]](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin/2.5.1/), but when I'm trying to download this artifact using Maven, it says:

```
Downloading: https://example.com/nexus/content/groups/all/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin/2.5.1/cobertura-maven-plugin-2.5.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:jar:2.5.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.523s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 16 16:31:24 EEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/219M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [16:31:24.647] Execute org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:cobertura done: 3978 ms
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] example project 1 ................................. FAILURE [10.077s]
[INFO] example project 2 ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.804s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 16 16:31:24 EEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/218M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:jar:2.5.1: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:pom:2.5.1 in example.com (https://example.com/nexus/content/groups/all) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project example project 1: Can not execute Sonar: Unable to execute maven plugin: Exception during execution of org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:cobertura -> [Help 2]
```

Any ideas why it can't download artifacts?

**UPD:** Yes, I've set mirror in settings.xml and yes, repository is 'In Service', and only reversed proxy is used.

Comment: Resolved by manual adding this artifact to the 3rd party repository. Will be grateful for better solution.

Comment: Now resolved by installation of the latest Nexus (2.0.4-1). The previous version was 1.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have your settings.xml pointing to the "all" group you have defined. In addition you have to override "central" for repository and pluginRepository (see http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) and ensure that central is part of your all group.

Once that is all good try your project again forcing updates with -U e.g.

```
mvn -U clean install
```

Comment: Manfred, thank you very much for your answer. But I don't have access to that server anymore, and therefore can't check it. Hope it will help others who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are often stored in different repositories than 'normal' artifacts (though as i understand it, there is no real reason why that needs to be so, just often done that way).

Double check your config and ensure the group you're pointing to has the *plugins* in central available. If you show your Nexus config, might be able to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by Nexus config? I have no access to the server where Nexus is, except via HTTPS. Therefore I can't see or change any configuration files at that server or view logs :(. But of course I have settings.xml and have administration access to server.